# Логическая ошибка при импорте данных в Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, es2016

Всем привет.
Есть 2 node.js модуля:

```js
console.time('test');

var respond;

var pgp = require('pg-promise')(/*options*/);

var cn = {
    host: 'localhost', // server name or IP address;
    port: 5432,
    database: 'trading_database_eur_usd',
    user: 'postgres',
    password: '7256'
};

var db = pgp(cn); // database instance;

// select and return user name from id:
db.any('SELECT * FROM eur_usd WHERE primary_key = 4623209;')
    .then(user => {
        respond = user;
    })
    .catch(error => {
        console.log(error); // print the error;
    });

module.exports = {
    databaseRespond: respond
};

console.timeEnd('test');
```

```js
const http = require('http');
const port = 2000;
m = require("../database/database.js");

const requestHandler = (request, response) => {
    response.writeHead(200);
    console.log(request.method);
    console.log(request.headers);
    console.log(request.url);
    response.write('hi');
    response.end();
};

const server = http.createServer(requestHandler);

server.listen(port, (err) => {
    if (err) {
        return console.log('something bad happened', err)
    }

    console.log(m.databaseRespond);
});
```

Задача состоит в том. что бы перебросить значение параметра 'user'  из первого модуля во второй;

Первое что мне пришло в голову это создать св-во 'databaseRespond' и положить в него вышеуказанный параметр через переменную 'respond' + затем передать все это дело через 'module.export'.

Но.
Почему то после запуска второго файла - консоль выводит:
{ databaseRespond: undefined }

Вопросы:

1) Почему это происходит?
Ведь в первом файле можно через дебаггер наблюдать как результат лежит в необходимом св-ве:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

2) Какие есть альтернативные решения подобной задачи с импортом?

3) Как реализовать решение правильнее всего с точки зрения семантики и т.п.

Comment: m = require("../database/database.js"); const забыл или как?

Comment: Первый модуль нужно оформить в виде функции которая возвращает результат запроса в бд, и экспортировать эту функцию, а во втором модуле эту функцию нужно вызвать.

Comment: потому что у вас асинхронна операция, создайте функцию возвращающую промис и вызывайте ее соответствующее в другом модуле

Comment: я так и подозревал что это с асинхронностью связано.
А можите хотя бы в общих чертах написать как ваш пример выглядеть должен?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я бы так сделал.
1 файл

```
const func = function(db){
    return db.any('SELECT * FROM eur_usd WHERE primary_key = 4623209;');
}
module.exports = func;
```

2 файл добавляете

```
var pgp = require('pg-promise')(/*options*/);

var cn = {
    host: 'localhost', // server name or IP address;
    port: 5432,
    database: 'trading_database_eur_usd',
    user: 'postgres',
    password: '7256'
};

var db = pgp(cn);
```

и в конце

```
m(db).then(res=>console.log(res)).catch(err=>console.log(err));
```