# Логическая ошибка при импорте данных в Node.js(Часть 2-я)

Tags: javascript, node.js, es2016

Народ! ) 
Кто нибудь может обьяснить почему при вызове вот такого кода:

```js
console.time('test');

    var pgp = require('pg-promise')(/*options*/);

    var cn = {
        host: 'localhost', // server name or IP address;
        port: 5432,
        database: 'trading_database_eur_usd',
        user: 'postgres',
        password: '7256'
    };

    var db = pgp(cn); // database instance;

    // select and return user name from id:

var promise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {

    db.any('SELECT * FROM eur_usd WHERE primary_key = 4623209;')
        .then(user => {
            resolve(user);
        })
        .catch(error => {
            reject(console.log(error)); // print the error;
        });

});


module.exports = {
    db: promise
      .then(
        result => {
          // первая функция-обработчик - запустится при вызове resolve
          result; // result - аргумент resolve
          console.log(result);
        },
        error => {
          // вторая функция - запустится при вызове reject
          console.log(error); // error - аргумент reject
        }
      )
};


console.timeEnd('test');
```

В консоли выводится результат:

```
"test: 103.301ms
[ { ticket: 'EURUSD',
    year_month_day: '20030505',
    hour_min_sec: '030000',
    open_price: '1.12161',
    high_price: '1.12209',
    low_price: '1.12161',
    close_price: '1.12209',
    volume: 561,
    primary_key: 4623209 } ]"
```

Но!
Если анализировать код через дебаггер - то получается противоположенный(как по мне) итог:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вопрос:
Почему это проиcходит?

P.S. Если вызвать вышеописанный код(без консоли лог) из другой страницы:

```js
const http = require('http');
const port = 2000;
const m = require("../database/database.js");

const requestHandler = (request, response) => {
    response.writeHead(200);
    console.log(request.method);
    console.log(request.headers);
    console.log(request.url);
    response.write('hi');
    response.end();
};

const server = http.createServer(requestHandler);

server.listen(port, (err) => {
    if (err) {
        return console.log('something bad happened', err)
    }

    console.log(m);
});
```

То вывод будет следующим:

```
{ db: Promise { <pending> } }
```

Конкретно на этих 3-х выводах(2 консоли + 1 дебаггер) я совсем запутался в плане понимания работы методов промисов - почему это происходит именно таким образом.
Если перефразировать:
То можно ли не меняя эти 2 страницы кода кардинально - заставить все таки вывести из второй страницы результат который по идее должен отдавать промис?
(т.е. то что выводит в первом примере консоль лог - мне необходимо получить на второй странице и например вывести это в консоль лог уже там.)

Comment: чем данный вопрос отличается от [предыдущего](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/903269/186999)?

Comment: туда нельзя добавить вопрос в таком формате.
(нет кнопки 'ответа на вопрос')

Comment: не понял. Если хочешь задать отдельный вопрос, зачем тебе кнопка ответа?

Comment: а каким образом можно тогда задать вопрос еще с поддержкой вложенного кода и что бы мозги себе не ломать т.к. это сделано в разделе добавить комментарий?

Comment: Никаким, это делается просто _отдельным_ вопросом. Либо можно отредактировать уже существующий вопрос. Но у тебя два вопроса, по сути, одинаковые: ты хочешь узнать, как дождаться окончания асинхронной функции. В вопросе дубликате - это описано.

Comment: там совсем другой пример качественно - он полностью убивает структуру этого примера.
Это не дает возможность понять механику процесса..
Это и так отдельный вопрос.

Comment: По поводу картинки в этом вопросе: debugger делает вывод **до** того, как Promise завершился, поэтому выводит состояние `pending`, а так как состояние `pending`, никакого значения быть не может.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/85625/discussion-between-grundy-and-mike-kharkov).